# How to deal with OP comments which go off-topic?

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

There have been a few times now when I've answered a question correctly, and the OP has marked my answer as correct, but then they have commented on my answer with further issues they are having. See this answer for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10086774/370103

I believe the OP has now gone off-topic with the comments. With this question the OP originally asked how to bind data to their jquery control. I've provided an answer, but it now seems they're having an unrelated issue.

What is the best way of dealing with this? Should the OP open a new question in this instance?

Comment: my personal preference is to [reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045485/camera-snapshot-in-j2me-null-pointer-exception/10052295#comment12875466_10052295 "example comment") with comments like this: **"that would be a [different question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "explanation about 'chameleon' questions"). Feel free to post it separately if you're interested"**